# Why is the image not shown while share?(description inside)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use facebook share on my website i'm building but in some pages the images is not shown. I've used the [object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to debug the url, I've found it is not showing the image from certain url like http://www.ebay.in/itm/HIGH-QUALITY-PORTABLE-BLUETOOTH-SPEAKERS-/121174412628, I don't get it why the image is not shown.

could you please say me the reason for it and a way to show image.

Comment: visit that url and check the size of the image it is 500 x 500px..

Comment: me too facing issue with some images! guess its a bug with fb!